# Django: Rest Framework (Serializer)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to using the django rest framework.

I'm trying to understand how I can validate a field with the serializer based on the input from the user, for example:

Serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

VALID_REGION = 'region'

def validate_region(value):
    
    if value != VALID_REGION:
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Invalid region, make sure region parameter is spelled correctly.')
    
    return value

class RegionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    region = serializers.CharField(required=False, validators=[validate_region])
```

Here I want to validate that the region is spelled correctly.

```
views.py

 def get(request, *args, **kwargs):

        serializer = RegionSerializer(data = request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            
            data = serializer.validated_data

            region   = data.get('region', '')

            regions = region_lib.get_regions(region)

            return Response({"regions" : regions}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        else:
            errors = serializer.errors

            return Response({"error" : errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Here I pass 'regoin' misspelling it intentionally.

```
{
    "regoin": "Test"
}
```

When I run `serializer.is_valid()` it returns `true`.

Not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify your request method from `GET` to `POST`. For example, change the following code:

From:

`def get(request, *args, **kwargs):`

To

`def post(request, *args, **kwargs):`

By using `def get(request, *args, **kwargs):`, your endpoint only allows `GET` requests. As a result, you cannot send a request body, and `self.request.data` will be `{}`. Additionally, in your `RegionSerializer`, you have set the region field to be optional with `required=False`:

`region = serializers.CharField(required=False, validators=[validate_region])`

This explains why `serializer.is_valid()` in your views always returns `True`.

When you change from `def get(request, *args, **kwargs):` (GET) to `def post(request, *args, **kwargs):` (POST), and you pass your request body as follows:

`{"region": "region"}`

This will pass the `serializer.is_valid()` check.

However, if you pass `{"region": "Region"}`, it will not cause `serializer.is_valid()` to return False.

Note: If your request body is empty, `serializer.is_valid()` will also return `True` since the `region` field is optional.